# Load txt file into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am still learning SQL Server.

The scenario is that I have a lot of `.txt` files with name format like `DIAGNOSIS.YYMMDDHHSS.txt` and only the `YYMMDDHHSS` is different from file to file. They are all saved in folder `Z:\diagnosis`.

How could I write a stored procedure to upload all `.txt` files with a name in the format of `DIAGNOSIS.YYMMDDHHSS.txt` in folder `Z:\diagnosis`? Files can only be loaded once.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would not do it using a stored proc. I would use SSIS. It has a for each file task you can use. When the file has been loaded, I would move it to an archive location so that it doesn't get processed the next time. Alternatively you could create a table where you store the names of the files that were successfully processed and have the for each file loop skip any in that table, but then you just keep getting more and more files to loop through, better to move processed ones to a different location if you can.

And personally I also would put the file data in a staging table before loading the data to the final table.  We use two of them, one for the raw data and one for the cleaned data. Then we transform to staging tables that match the relational tables in production to make sure the data will meet the needs there before trying to affect production and send exceptions to an exception table of records that can't be inserted for one reason or another. Working in the health care environment you will want to make sure your process meets the government regulations for storage of patient records for the country you are in if they exist (See HIPAA in the US). You may have to load directly to production or severely limit the access to staging tables and files.

Comment: Something like this...

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/